# N and M are positive integers having same digits but in different order, N + M = 10^10, then prove that N is divisible by 10.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, divisibility

> "N and M are positive integers having same digits but in different order, $$N + M = 10^{10}$$ then prove that N is divisible by 10."

I have tried solving the question but to no avail. Please help.

Comment: It is equivalent to prove that both have to be divisible by 10. That means the unit place on both must be 0. Maybe proof by contradiction will work

Comment: Hint: consider the least significant non-zero digit in $N$ - call this $a$. What must the counterpart digit in $M$ be? What can be said about more significant digits? Think about the condition about having the same digits.

Comment: @Mark, is it necessary for the unit place in both to be zero. Is there any proof for that ?

Comment: If one is zero, the other must be - think about having to add the units to get a zero on the units place. Either you need two zeros, or you need the units digits to add to $10$ to give the zero, and you have a "carry".

Comment: But what if the digit in the ten's place adds up with the carry to give a zero and this goes on for a certain steps until finally we end up with a power of ten. Can you counter this?

Comment: That is what you need to think about - as an example $275+725=1000=10^3$, but how do you get $10^{10}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the last two digits $p$ and $q$ of $M$ and $N$ are not zero. It means that $p+q=10$.

**Case 1:** $p\ne q$

Let us first consider the case where $p\ne q$. I will use concrete values for $p,q$ but you can replace them with any other two. Suppose $p=6$, $q=4$.

The numbers $M,N$ are:

$$.........6 \\
.........4$$

Now, number 4 has to appear somewhere in the first number:

$$..4......6 \\
.........4$$

Under that number we must have digit 5 in the second number:

$$..4......6 \\
..5......4$$

Now you have 5 in the second number, it has to appear somewhere in the first:

$$..4.5....6 \\
..5......4$$

The matching number under it has to be 4:

$$..4.5....6 \\
..5.4....4$$

But now you have two 4s in the second number so you have to add one more to the first number and again add one 5 below it:

$$..4.5..4.6 \\
..5.4..5.4$$

But now you have the wrong count of 5s... and you are clearly in the infinite loop that you cannot exit.

**Case 2:** $p=q=5$

We have ten digit numbers both ending in 5:

$$.........5\\
.........5
$$

We have to fill 9 remaining positions in each number.

Missing digits come in pairs with their sum equal to 9 (digits cannot be equal, obviously). For example:

$$.3.......5\\
.6.......5
$$

But to keep the same digits in both numbers you have to put 6 into the first number and 3 into the last number:

$$.3..6....5\\
.6..3....5
$$

We have 7 positions left. Pick any two digits and you will have only five empty positions left:

$$.3..62.7.5\\
.6..37.2.5
$$

Eventually, you will end up with two incomplete numbers with all the same digits, just in a different order, and one empty position in each one. Whatever you choose to put there will break the "symmetry", your numbers won't have the same collection of digits.

Based on these two cases, we have a conclusion: the only way to construct the requested numbers is to start with $p=q=0$.